# How to run multiple line sql query using PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
spark.sql("Select acts.accountname, acts.county_state,loc.Town, acts.country from assure_crm_accounts acts inner join assure_crm_accountlocation loc on acts.GPAddressCode = loc.GPAddressCode").show(30, False)
```

I run into error when I use multiple line query using PySpark, is there a way to run multiple line queries using a single command?

Comment: Maybe it's handy to write it on 1 line, then after that use auto-reformatting shortcut in you editor. Then you see what's the best syntax!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put " \" at the end of each line:

```
spark.sql("Select acts.accountname, acts.county_state,loc.Town, acts.country from \
assure_crm_accounts acts inner join assure_crm_accountlocation loc on \
acts.GPAddressCode = loc.GPAddressCode").show(30, False)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use triple quotes to write multiline string sql query as below:

```
spark.sql("""
Select acts.accountname, acts.county_state,loc.Town, acts.country 
from assure_crm_accounts acts 
inner join assure_crm_accountlocation loc 
on acts.GPAddressCode = loc.GPAddressCode
"""
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this - it is the only reference I've found that doesn't require the \ character (which is a real pain for very large SQL statements).